# How to use std::sort with an std::array?

Tags: c++, sorting, stdarray

I need to sort an `std::array`, but I can't figure out how to do that using the `std::sort()` function, since I get the errors "no instance of overloaded function sort matches the argument list" and "no operator '+' matches these operands". When I use the same syntax to try to sort a regular array, I have no errors.
Here is code which produces the problem:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int nums[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::array<int, 5> morenums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};


int main(){
    std::sort(nums, nums + 5);//no error
    std::sort(morenums, morenums + 5);//error    
}
```

I was trying to use the `std::sort()` method to sort an `std::array`, but I couldn't figure out how to do this, since I kept getting errors.

Comment: See the [`std::sort` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort#Example).

Comment: You could solve this by reading about [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of guessing and assuming.

Comment: In all C++ standards, `std::sort(morenums.begin(), morenums.end())` will work, since all standard library containers have `begin()` and `end()` member functions.  C++11 and later, there are also `std::begin()` and `std::end()` which work with both raw arrays and standard containers, so you could replace the body of your `main()` with `std::sort(std::begin(nums), std::end(nums)); std::sort(std::begin(morenums), std::end(morenums));` - which, among other things, avoids the need to hard-code the value `5` in the arguments of `std::sort()`.

Comment: `std::array` doesn't decay to a pointer (or some other kind of iterator. You need to use an iterator. The closest equivalent to the code using an array would be `std::sort(morenums.begin(), morenums.begin() + 5);`, but I'd prefer the other suggestions made here... (Technically `std::sort(morenums.data(), morenums.data() + 5);` may be even closer to the first `std::sort` call, but I'd definetly avoid that version...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Same as you would sort any other container, such as `std::vector`:

```
std::sort(morenums.begin(), morenums.end());
```

It's the plain arrays that have the odd syntax, not `std::array`.

You can also do `std::sort(std::begin(morenums), std::end(morenums));` or `std::ranges::sort(morenums);`, those work for both plain arrays and containers.

Answer (score 3):

`std::sort()` and in fact many other algorithms in the STL make use of iterators. Iterators are classes which you can at least dereference (`*`) and increment(`++`) and they usually point to an element in a range of elements. They can point to invalid elements, such as the `.end()` method of e.g. a `std::array` or other STL containers (which points to the element after the last valid element).

The most basic form of an iterator is a raw pointer, which supports increment, dereference and also pointer arithmetic which you made use of. In your example `int nums[5]` is just a c-style array, which can decay into a pointer to its first element.

Therefore `std::sort(nums, nums + 5)` does the same as `std::sort(&nums[0], &nums[5])` would do, with `nums[5]` being one element to far, but that is ok since it will not get dereferenced and is just what `std::sort()` expects.

However `std::sort(morenums, morenums + 5)` does not work, since `morenums` is a normal class (not an iterator), doesn't decay into a pointer and you can't do addition with it. However `std::array` comes with the methods `.begin()` and `.end()`, which return exactly those two iterators (or more complex pointers) you need for `std::sort()`. `.begin()` points to the first valid element (`morenums[0]`) and `.end()` again to the next element after the last valid one. With use of those iterators you don't need to care about the size of your `std::array`, as you needed to with the c-style array.

You could use `std::sort(&morenums[0], &morenums[0] + morenums.size())` to sort your `std::array` too, which would use pointers and not the iterator class, but this is just for demonstration and is the same as you did with your c-style array. However you should **not** use this in real code, rather just use the iterators that come with `std::array`. This approach with pointers works for `std::array`, since all elements are in order, each element is just at the next memory location, but it might not work for other containers which don't store elements in one contiguous block of memory.

---

To make your example work, you can change the line in which you attempt to sort the `std::array` to `std::sort(morenums.begin(), morenums.end());` and your working code would look like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int nums[5] = { 5, 2, 3, 4, 1 };
std::array<int, 5> morenums = { 1, 2, 5, 4, 3 };


int main() {
    std::sort(nums, nums + 5);
    std::sort(morenums.begin(), morenums.end()); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: both examples should be `std::sort(std::begin(nums), std::end(nums))` and `std::sort(std::begin(morenums), std::end(morenums))` as the free function take care of the various way you access the iterators/data for you and help make the code more generic

Comment: @Vivick What exactly would be the difference of using `std::begin()` or `.begin()`? I always thought that those would behave in the same way? And yes, I could use them for the c-style array, but I didn't want to, because someone might want to pass the array to a function and then `std::begin()` would not work on the decayed pointer.

Comment: `std::begin()` and `std::end()` work equally well with plain array, so they are preferred in template functions (actually, in a template, bring them in with `using` as a fallback for argument-dependent lookup: `using std::begin; using std::end; std::sort(begin(a), end(a));`